# Intercepting exceptions by types given on runtime

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I am writing windows runtime behavior for FlipView memory efficient image loading where I expose my `IImageSourceProvider` interface. Library users could write their own interface implementation (which implies that it could throw different types of exceptions) so I'm curious is it possible to intercept exceptions by type given in runtime (perhaps by some reflection) ? The main idea is to give library-users ability to register exceptions types and their handlers (because it's "xaml component" they won't be able to handle it in code at least without any "hacks").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C# one could specify which exceptions should be thrown in an implementation of the interface using comments

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1htk11d.aspx

This will leave it up to the implementer to wrap his exception a custom exception that your interface is allowed to throw.

Barring that you could catch a generic exception and then use reflection to inspect the type and properties of the caught exception class.